Flutter Web: problems with scrolling to begin or end in ListView after updating listview-items
I am building a Flutter Web app which provides an agenda. The agenda is presented in a ListView. I am fetching data from a backend to fill the agenda with future / past events. To avoid a huge list and lots of backend data I am loading chunks of 8 weeks and present that in my ListView.
I'd like to have an infinite-scrolling feel. If the user reaches the end of the list, the next 8 weeks are loaded and if the user scrolls to the top the previous 8 weeks are loaded. Of course I'd like to keep the UI as 'stable' as possible. Therefore, in these 8 week-chunks, the last or first viewed week is merged in the new data. After loading the new data, it would be wonderful if the old data remains visible. For that I need to adjust the scroll position. And that seems impossible.
If I hit the sweet spot which triggers loading the new data, the scrollbar seems to have 'momentum', it wants to keep on moving. For instance: I reach the top of the ListView, new data is loaded, I want the scrollposition to move to the bottom to make the last seen previous date visible. That kind of works, but the the scrollbar doesn't stop and moves on towards the top. As if it had too much speed and needs to move on instead of stopping at the bottom. Same thing happens when I go down, I'd like to move the scrollbar to the beginning, but it keeps on moving downwards.

Keeping the scroll-position steady after updating the data behind the ListView seems impossible. I've read numerous stackoverflow questions about that one. I've given up on that.
I have tried the scroll_to_index package and the scrollable_positioned_list, both packages can't slow down the scrollbar's momentum.
I have experimented with several physics types and wrapped my ListView in a ScrollConfiguration: no joy.

My main question boils down to this: how can I jump to a specific position in list and keep the scrollbar there?
At the moment I set a timer (1 sec) when the top or bottom of the ListView are hit. That almost stops the momentum of the scrollbar, like riding it out. After 1 sec the actual jumping is done. The result is a functioning but poor user experience.
Showing all the code seems a but much, here are the highlights of the current implementation.
Setting up a ScrollController in initState that listens to the trigger, waits for a second and then performs the jumpTo (loadAgenda preps and fetches the new agenda chunk):
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // fetch initial data
  loadAgenda();
  //
  _scrollController = ScrollController();
  // set listener
  _scrollController.addListener(() {
    double offset = _scrollController.offset;
    double maxOffset = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;

    if (offset == maxOffset) {
      if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();

      _debounce = Timer(_debounceDuration, () {
        loadAgenda(timeDirection: TimeDirection.future);
        _scrollController.jumpTo(agendaPadding);
      });
    }

    if (offset == 0) {
      if (_debounce?.isActive ?? false) _debounce!.cancel();

      _debounce = Timer(_debounceDuration, () {
        loadAgenda(timeDirection: TimeDirection.past);
        _scrollController.jumpTo(
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - agendaPadding);
      });
    }
  });
}

The ListView of the Agenda itself, every item is wrapped in an AgendaTile (height of item differs):
Expanded(
  child: ListView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        //
        if (_isFetchingData)
          const Center(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )),
        //
        for (var item in agenda)
          AgendaTile(
            date: item.$1,
            sessions: item.$2,
          ),
        //
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
      ]),

Last but not least: I am using Riverpod to keep state of the agenda.
What am I doing wrong?
